# output format change while writing in csv through R

Tags: r, csv

I am writing a file and i have data like:

```
data:

251481,1824787
290
286457
.....
```

But when I am writing using write.csv in csv file the output comes out to be

```
2,514,811,824,787
290
286,457


str(data)
Factor w/ 247203 levels "1000014","1000019",..: 235247 48293 60168 157447 171828 180277 193274 198102 217196 229307 ...
```

I am using:

```
write.csv(data,"..../data.csv)
```

How can i deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: could you post the output of `str(data)`

Comment: Have you tried `write.table(data, sep = ",", col.names = FALSE)` ?

Comment: @RichardScriven: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think that `write.csv` by default have some predefined options about numbers output, you could disable them or use other writer, like `write.csv2`, see the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/write.table.html) for more information. The option is `keep.source = TRUE` if I understand correctly these [post](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg69579.html)